# Correct way to test for numpy.dtype

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking at a third-party lib that has the following `if`-test:

```
if isinstance(xx_, numpy.ndarray) and xx_.dtype is numpy.float64 and xx_.flags.contiguous:
    xx_[:] = ctypes.cast(xx_.ctypes._as_parameter_,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))
```

It appears that `xx_.dtype is numpy.float64` always fails:

```
>>> xx_ = numpy.zeros(8, dtype=numpy.float64)
>>> xx_.dtype is numpy.float64

False
```

What is the correct way to test that the `dtype` of a numpy array is `float64` ?

Comment: First, why do you have both `numpy` and `np` in the same script? Is there any chance they're different copies of the module? (Try `numpy is np` to see…)

Comment: typo - fixed now. That later example is just to demonstrate a test showing the comparison always fails, it's not part of the third-party lib

Comment: As, then I didn't really need to prove the same thing in my answer that you already knew, and could have made it shorter. Oh well. :)

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, could you edit you answer to provide the correct way to do the test? I think I'll edit my question to make that more the focus, as doing the test correctly will be of more interest to anyone looking at this question in the future.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the right test is. It's probably `==`, but, without knowing why it's checking, it may not be. I'll try to write the answer to convey that.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is a bug in the lib.

[`dtype` objects](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) can be constructed dynamically. And NumPy does so all the time. There's no guarantee anywhere that they're interned, so constructing a `dtype` that already exists will give you the same one.

On top of that, `np.float64` isn't actually a `dtype`; it's a… I don't know what these types are called, but the types used to construct scalar objects out of array bytes, which are usually found in the `type` attribute of a `dtype`, so I'm going to call it a `dtype.type`. (Note that `np.float64` subclasses both NumPy's numeric tower types and Python's numeric tower ABCs, while `np.dtype` of course doesn't.)

Normally, you can use these interchangeably; when you use a `dtype.type`—or, for that matter, a native Python numeric type—where a `dtype` was expected, a `dtype` is constructed on the fly (which, again, is not guaranteed to be interned), but of course that doesn't mean they're identical:

```
>>> np.float64 == np.dtype(np.float64) == np.dtype('float64') 
True
>>> np.float64 == np.dtype(np.float64).type
True
```

The `dtype.type` usually *will* be identical if you're using builtin types:

```
>>> np.float64 is np.dtype(np.float64).type
True
```

But two `dtype`s are often not:

```
>>> np.dtype(np.float64) is np.dtype('float64')
False
```

But again, none of that is guaranteed. (Also, note that `np.float64` and `float` use the exact same storage, but are separate types. And of course you can also make a `dtype('f8')`, which is guaranteed to work the same as `dtype(np.float64)`, but that doesn't mean `'f8'` `is`, or even `==`, `np.float64`.)

So, it's possible that constructing an array by explicitly passing `np.float64` as its `dtype` argument will mean you get back the same instance when you check the `dtype.type` attribute, but that isn't guaranteed. And if you pass `np.dtype('float64')`, or you ask NumPy to infer it from the data, or you pass a dtype string for it to parse like `'f8'`, etc., it's even less likely to match. More importantly, you *definitely* not get `np.float64` back as the `dtype` itself.

---

So, how should it be fixed?

Well, the docs define what it means for two `dtype`s to be *equal*, and that's a useful thing, and I think it's probably the useful thing you're looking for here. So, just replace the `is` with `==`:

```
if isinstance(xx_, numpy.ndarray) and xx_.dtype == numpy.float64 and xx_.flags.contiguous:
```

However, to some extent I'm only guessing that's what you're looking for. (The fact that it's checking the contiguous flag implies that it's probably going to go right into the internal storage… but then why isn't it checking C vs. Fortran order, or byte order, or anything else?)

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
x = np.zeros(8, dtype=np.float64)
print x.dtype is np.dtype(np.float64))
```

`is` tests for the identity of 2 objects, whether they have the same `id()`.  It is used for example to test `is None`, but can give errors when testing for integers or strings.  But in this case, there's a further problem, `x.dtype` and `np.float64` are not the same class.

```
isinstance(x.dtype, np.dtype)  # True
isinstance(np.float64, np.dtype) # False


x.dtype.__class__  # numpy.dtype
np.float64.__class__ # type
```

`np.float64` is actually a function.  `np.float64()` produces `0.0`.  `x.dtype()` produces an error.  (correction `np.float64` is a class.)

In my interactive tests:

```
x.dtype is np.dtype(np.float64)
```

returns `True`.  But I don't know if that's universally the case, or just the result of some sort of local caching.  The `dtype` documentation mentions a `dtype` attribute:

> dtype.num     A unique number for each of the 21 different built-in types.

Both dtypes give `12` for this `num`.

```
x.dtype == np.float64
```

tests `True`.

Also, using `type` works:

```
x.dtype.type is np.float64  # True
```

---

When I import `ctypes` and do the `cast` (with your `xx_`) I get an error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I don't know enough of `ctypes` to understand what it is trying to do.  It looks like it is doing a type conversion of the `data` pointer of `xx_`, `xx_.ctypes._as_parameter_` is the same number as `xx_.__array_interface__['data'][0]`.

---

In the `numpy` test code I find these dtype tests:

```
issubclass(arr.dtype.type, (nt.integer, nt.bool_)
assert_(dat.dtype.type is np.float64)
assert_equal(A.dtype.type, np.unicode_)
assert_equal(r['col1'].dtype.kind, 'i')
```

`numpy` documentation also talks about

```
np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.float64)
np.issubsctype(x, np.float64)
```

both of which use `issubclass`.

---

Further tracing of the `c` code suggests that `x.dtype == np.float64` is evaluated as:

```
x.dtype.num == np.dtype(np.float64).num
```

That is, the scalar type is converted to a `dtype`, and the `.num` attributes compared.  The code is in `scalarapi.c`, `descriptor.c`, `multiarraymodule.c` of `numpy / core / src / multiarray`

Comment: There's some useful information here. It's true that a `dtype` has a `type`, which is the class used to construct scalars of the type, and not the same as the `dtype` itself, and that `float64` is the latter, not the former. On the other hand, it's not true that `float64` is actually a function (the fact that its type is `type` proves that). And you can generally use a `dtype.type` wherever you can use a `dtype`; doing so just constructs a new `dtype` object on the fly. Note that `dtype('float64') == dtype(float64) == float64`. And I think the last one is key to what the OP cares about here.

Comment: OK, `np.float64' isn't a function.  Would callable class be more accurate?

Comment: Well, _all_ classes are callable. I don't understand what contrast you're aiming for there.

Comment: You're right.  I was thinking of class objects being callable, which isn't the case here.  I'm trying to pin down the difference between a `type` like `float64` and a `dtype`.  Do you know where the `__eq__` for `dtype` is defined (or its equivalent in `c` code)?

Comment: For the first half, the difference is that a `float64` is a numeric type. I don't know what the right term for those is, but it's similar to the builtin `float` (in fact, nearly interchangeable with it; IIRC, it's just a subclass that also inherits from the NumPy numeric tower types) or `int`. The same way you can construct `np.dtype(float)`, you can construct `np.dtype(float64)`. And the same way you can just pass `float` anywhere a `dtype` is expected, you can pass `float64`.

Comment: For the second half, I think it's [`arraydescr_richcompare`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/descriptor.c#L3402), which just defers to the NumPy public-API function `PyArray_EquivTypes`, but that's from a very quick scan, so don't trust it too far…

Comment: Starting with `richcompare` I traced the code and I think the `np.float64` type is wrapped in `dtype`, and the `.num` attributes are compared.

Comment: Yeah, IIRC, comparing a dtype to anything else constructs a dtype out of that anything else; then, if both dtypes are either numpy types or native Python types, they're compared by numpy type numbers or Python type objects. Anyway, I think it's more important to figure out what's documented (and therefore likely to be the same between 1.8 and 1.9, NumPy and NumPyPy, different builds/platforms, etc.) than how it's implemented, unless you're actually writing implementation-level code.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure when this API was introduced, but at least as of 2022 it looks like you can use [numpy.issubdtype](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.issubdtype.html) for the type checking part and therefore write:

```
if isinstance(arr, numpy.ndarray) and numpy.issubdtype(arr.dtype, numpy.floating):
    ...
```